# failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-stream-22983.git'

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to push my project to Heroku but when I `git push heroku master` this error is showing up:

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to enigmatic-stream-22983.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-stream-22983.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-stream-22983.git'
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.5'


gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'

gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'

gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'


gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'

  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do

  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'mini_racer'
end



gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myrecipes",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }

}
```

`application.rb`:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

module Myrecipes
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  end


end
```

`config/webpack/production.js`:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Comment: Have you verified the app runs correctly locally? Also is your Gemflie.lock up to date with your Gemfile (meaning, you have run `bundle` and committed the changes it makes to Gemfile.lock) ?

Comment: I didn't write that comment... paging @C-RAD

Comment: @C-RAD
yes, I run my program locally without any problems, and i did these steps(meaning,  run bundle and committed the changes )

Comment: my os is : windows 10 pro x64

Comment: ohhh! finally my problem solved....
i just  add uglifier to my gemfile ,, and job done...

Comment: The important part of your log output is before / above what you're showing us.